# form POST in iframe without affecting history

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, browser-history

Is it possible to submit a form inside an iframe without affecting the browser's history?

I've implemented sending a cross domain POST request.  It uses Javascript to create and submit a form inside an iframe.  It works, but each request adds an item to the browser's history.

Anyone know a way around this?  I've tried creating the iframe with both innerHTML and createElement.  I've seen no difference so far.

PS - I would love to use XMLHtttpRequest ("Ajax"), but it doesn't support sending data across domains.  And I would love to use GET instead of post, but I need to send more than 2k of data.

Here's one version of my code.  I've tried many variations and have searched all over, butI can't seem to find a solution that doesn't affect the browser's history.  I believe it's not possible -- can anyone confirm that?

```
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function submit(params) {

      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = '<iframe height="50" width="50"></iframe>';
      document.body.appendChild(div);

      var iframe = div.firstChild;
      var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
      iframeDocument.open();
      iframeDocument.close();

      var form = iframeDocument.createElement('form');
      iframeDocument.body.appendChild(form);
      form.setAttribute('action', 'http://some-other-domain.com/submit-here');
      form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');

      for (param in params) {
        var field = iframeDocument.createElement('input');
        field.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        field.setAttribute('name', param);
        field.setAttribute('value', params[param]);
        form.appendChild(field);
      }
      form.submit();
    }

    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
        submit({
          'x' : 'Some Value',
          'y' : 'Another Value',
          'z' : new Date().getTime()
        });
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Example of using Javascript to POST across domains...</h1>
  <input id="button" type="button" value="click to send">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why can't you just use ajax to submit the form? That would stop you from reloading any pages, which should free up your history. Am I missing something?

Comment: I need to post cross domain.  Ajax (XMLHttpRequest) POST doesn't support sending data to a domain which is different from the host page.

Comment: I think you actually can send a POST request vis ajax. See my updated answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: I think it's not possible .. (even if it was somehow, it would likely be browser-specific).

Comment: Brian do you have a final example of the code you used to solve this problem you could share?

Thx

Comment: The final solution was to 1) insert an iframe hosted on my domain 2) use the window.name hack to send data from the host page (on a different domain) to the iframe and 3) send an Ajax POST request to the server on my domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work to use JS to add an IFRAME whose src is hosted at your site (the domain to which the third-party-hosted script needs to send data?)  This IFRAME could include the needed Javascript to make an XMLHttpRequest to your/its domain.  And as for getting the actual data to this IFRAME from the third-party-site - try: http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes .  It's a pretty clever solution involving changing fragment identifiers (#something) at the end of the IFRAME URL, which you can then read via JS within the IFRAME.

Also a guess, but if you tack [this past SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821359/reload-an-iframe-without-adding-to-the-history) to a similar history problem (using location.replace) on to the above this hopefully should let you do the anchor-changing part without disrupting the history stack.

Comment: Very interesting!  It will take me some time to investigate, but this could be what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: It completely worked, and I'm now able to use Ajax within the iframe.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Thanks for reporting back here, I can see quite likely needing to use this approach myself in the near future.

Comment: I may have spoken too soon.  Safari doesn't record the iframe history, but other browsers do.  Still working this out.

http://www.tagneto.org/blogcode/xframe/ui.html

Comment: The final solution was to 1) insert an iframe hosted on my domain 2) use the window.name hack to send data from the host page (on a different domain) to the iframe and 3) send an Ajax POST request to the server on my domain.

Answer (score 3):

[You should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473038/post-versus-ajax-call) [use an](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163704/ajax-versus-frames) [AJAX](http://w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest.asp) [POST](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php).

> [Usually](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php) only the GET method is used while creating Ajax apps. But there are several occasions when POST is necessary when creating a ajax request. This could be for several reasons. For example, POST request are considered more secure than GET request as creating a POST request is relatively harder than creating a GET request.

AJAX calls aren't stored into the browsing history.

Comment: Useful links, you should follow them, but not really that much description.

Comment: @Shhnap: it was a bit of tough love. Anyway, added the relevant info that Brian needs.

Comment: Ajax POST doesn't work across domains.  The page will be hosted on one domain and will send data to another.  Additionally, the data is larger than 2k, so GET won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If your server can run code, you could probably do an ajax query to a "proxy" page on your server, that would then itself run the request on the remote server and return the results to your page.

Comment: I don't run the host domain.  I run the domain to which I need to send data.  The host page will include my code as a third-party script.  

Thank you though.

Comment: I see. A quick search seems to indicate it's possible to do using a flash proxy (see http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/000280.html). If you don't want to go down this route, I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: Flash is a little heavy-weight, but that's a good idea.  I'll definitely consider that.

Comment: Actually, the weight of flash isn't the issue.  The reason I can't use it that it doesn't work on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

(?) I don't see a good reason that you are using an iframe element. (Since this was an older question, maybe you were testing in 1997-vintage HTML 4.  BTW, ignore the "XML" in the object name - it's a carry over from the year 2000 and later versions of [X]HTML - no XML required.)

If you send the HTTP request from JavaScript rather than from elements in the document, nothing will be added to the history.

```
function httpPost(body) {
  req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("POST", "/submit-here", true/*async*/);
     // or "http://some-other-domain.com/submit-here"
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  req.send(body);
}
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
      httpPost('x=Some+Value&y=Another+Value&z=' + new Date().getTime());
      // or use a buildQuery function, JQuery formSerialize, etc. to create the body
   }
}
```

I use symbolic links ("ln -s ...") so that the forms can be submitted to the same domain as the document, so in my case the "/submit-here" is a relative URI.

Answer (score -2):

As made in the comments, the solution to this problem is in making an AJAX request from your server instead of trying to submit the page normally. W3schools has a really good introduction to AJAX that you can find here: http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp

Essentially, AJAX uses javascript to send a request to the server and displays the response and because it happens using Pure javascript then the page does not reload and history is not affected at all. Which sounds like exactly what you want.

Edit: **AJAX can not post data.**

I actually think it can; or at least there are some workarounds that let you post data. See here:

http://www.captain.at/howto-ajax-form-post-request.php

That seems to do it in a rather straightforward manner. See the code at the bottom of the page. Specifically:

```
http_request.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
http_request.open('POST', url, true);
http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);
http_request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
http_request.send(parameters);
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest supports POST, but it doesn't support sending data across domains.