# zend - upload file with REST services

Tags: php, web-services, file, zend-framework, upload

i use zend framework and work with some web services(insert, update, delete but with int, string parameters). Now i don't how to upload file(for example image) with zend and web services(REST). Does anyone have some example?

Answer (score 1):

You should send the file throught post call. The Rest service will receive the postAction as when you do what ever other functions. But, with files you cannot make the calls with ajax, so you have a little trick to do in client side.

Remember, REST service will implement post action and receive the parameters as you would receive normally. If you know how to receive and manipulate a file with standard php, you can do it in REST service implementation.

The trick on client side is to create an invisible iFrame and redirect the submit form target to it.

This links explain this method very well with code samples:

[form POST in iframe without affecting history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597548/form-post-in-iframe-without-affecting-history)

http://ajaxpatterns.org/IFrame_Call

http://geekswithblogs.net/rashid/archive/2007/08/01/Create-An-Ajax-Style-File-Upload.aspx

http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/11/ajax-style-file-uploading-using-hidden-iframe.html

Namastê !!