# Windows Authentication over XMLHttpRequest

Tags: ajax, wcf, model-view-controller, xmlhttprequest, windows-authentication

Here's my scenario:

My client is running on DomainA. The client hits a MVC web application on DomainB and is prompted for their logon credentials, which they provide and are successfully granted access to the application.

Now, when the application tries to make an XMLHttpRequest to a WCF service (running on DomainB also, same server, different port), the user is prompted again for their DomainB logon credentials.

**Is there a way to pass the user's DomainB credentials along with the XMLHttpRequest?**

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to submit ajax requests through a secure server (Windows Authentication on IIS in my case) was to use iframes for all the POST requests, although get requests work through the xml request object. It actually works really well.

The only side effect of frame ajax is the browser history is filled with each request. Just make sure the javascript isn't executed again and it isn't much of a problem. You can also try manipulating the history with javascript, although I've ran into interesting bugs when trying that.

As far as multiple domains goes, I was just reading another SO post about that: [form POST in iframe without affecting history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597548/form-post-in-iframe-without-affecting-history)